# Validation on class instantiation

Tags: python, validation, class

all
I have a question for class instantiation in python. 
So I have a bunch of data of different types stored in the same directory and I only want to process one type of them using the python class only good for that type. Unfortunately the type of the data is only known when it is read in through the class. 
So I wonder if there is a way to simply stop the class instantiation in `__init__()` if the data type is not correct and just simply pass to the next dataset when reading all the data in? 
Or it is a bad idea to validate upon a class instantiation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you clarify why "the data type is only known when it is read through the class" with a more concrete example of your data.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, so the data is in netcdf format, and I can only know it is whether an image or a spectra when I read it in and look for its 'TYPE' attribute through the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to *raise an error* if the data fed to the class is the wrong type:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        if not isinstance(data, correct_type):
            raise TypeError("data argument must be of type X")
```

And then wrap your instantiation with a try except clause:

```
try:
    myInstance = MyClass(questionable_data)

except TypeError:
    #data is not the correct type. "pass" or handle in an alternative way.
```

This is advantageous because it makes the fact that the data needs to be a certain type explicitly obvious.

Another option is to do as sberry said, and explicitly test the data type *before* attempting to instantiate a class:

```
if isinstance(data, correct_type):
    myInstance = MyClass(data)
else:
    #data is not the correct type. "pass" or handle in an alternative way.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        if type(data) is int:  #In this example we don't want an int, we want anything else
            pass
        else:
            #do stuff here
```

Then use it like:

```
MyClass('This is ok')
```

or

```
MyClass(92) #This is not ok
```

Comment: How does this stop instantiation?  Also, why not `if isinstance(data, int): foo = MyClass(data)`

Comment: This is good enough for me, though it still instantiates it. But I guess it won't take much memory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best place to do validation would be at the setters function,doing validation at `def __init__()` can be by passed using dot notation

**Example**
Suppose we have a class account that takes in name and amount. The name shouldnt be blank and amount should be negative.

```
class Account:
  def __init__(self, name, amount):
      # validation code
    if not name:
       raise ValueError("name shouldnt be blank")
    if amount < 0:
       raise ValueError("amount shouldnt be negative")
    self.name = name
    self.amount = amount
```

*Somewhere in our code*

```
savings = Account('locked savings', 100)
```

We can mutate the values stored in savings in such a way that our validation code never runs(since its only executed when instantiating) ie

```
savings.name = ''
savings.amount = -3999
```

To avoid this, just put all the validation code in your setters